# Calling default FsCheck generator from a custom generator of the same type

Tags: f#, fscheck, property-based-testing

I defined a type with a few custom generators to make FsCheck generate customized instances of a few types. But for one of the complex types I want to use default FsCheck generation first and then adjust the result. Here's a (simplified) code:

```
type CustomGenerators =
    static member FirstCustomType() = /* function that returns FirstCustomType */
    static member SecondCustomType() =
        Arb.generate<SecondCustomType>
        |> Gen.map (fun x -> /* adjust some data in the generated instance */)
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

The problem is that when SecondCustomType() static method calls Arb.generate it immediately calls SecondCustomType() causing an endless recursion. I understand that Arb.generate must respect custom generators, so this is why it calls static SecondCustomType(), but I need to call the default (not customized) Arb.generate implementation for SecondCustomType. I can't call the implementation from a different type because my custom generator uses custom generator for FirstCustomType, so default SecondCustomType implementation must be aware of all custom generators defined in CustomGenerators type. This is a sort of a bad circle which I haven't yet found a clean resolution for (only workaround).

Comment: I would suggest wrapping `SecondCustomType` in a trivial wrapper just for test, say `SecondCustomTypeTestWrapper`, define the custom generator for that wrapper, not for `SecondCustomType` itself, and have your test take the wrapper as parameter.

Comment: Yes this is what I already did, but I was wondering if there is a better way without additional type wrapper.

Comment: Instead of immediately defining arbitraries in static classes, couldn't you define some normal F# functions that return gen values, and then compose them as you need them? That's what I normally do, but then I never use static convention-based classes...

Comment: It'd be easier to provide a concrete answer if you can post a small repro.

Comment: I tried that but encountered deadly recursion. I will try extracting an example to illustrate what is happening.

Comment: @MarkSeemann perhaps I got too attached to the technique that you demonstrated in your course, but I've found the method of deriving from Property a custom attribute and providing custom generators in a custom type to be very efficient. It appears that Fyodor's suggestion worked nicely - use of Arb.Default.Derive did the trick and I no longer get the endless recursive calls caused by Arb.generate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the "default" (i.e. provided out of the box) generators are on the [`FsCheck.Arb.Default`](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L259) class. Depending on what your `SecondCustomType` actually is, you can use some of the methods on that class, such as [`Bool`](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L268) or [`String`](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L422).

If your type is a proper algebraic F# type (i.e. union, record, or tuple), you can take advantage of the automatically derived generator for such types that is represented by [`Default.Derive`](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/master/src/FsCheck/Arbitrary.fs#L933).

```
type CustomGenerators =
    static member SecondCustomType() =
        Arb.Default.Derive<SecondCustomType>()
        |> Arb.toGen
        |> Gen.map (fun x -> (* adjust some data in the generated instance *) )
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

---

Having said that, I would agree with Mark's comment above: using these static-method-shim-for-type-class generators will always be kinda awkward. Just like Mark, I much prefer to have FsCheck provide what it can provide out of the box, and then compose the desired input using regular functions. I'll give you an example.

Consider this type that, presumably, can't be generated by FsCheck out of the box:

```
type SomeAwkwardType( name: string, id: int, flag: bool ) =
   member this.Name = name
   member this.Id = id
   member this.Flag = flag
```

Here's the awkward way using the static-shim-for-type-class generator:

```
type AwkwardTypeGenerator() =
   static member Gen() =
      gen {
         let! name = Arb.generate<string>
         let! id = Arb.generate<int>
         let! flag = Arb.generate<bool>
         return SomeAwkwardType( name, id, flag )
      }

module Tests =
   let [Property] ``Test using the awkward generator`` (input: SomeAwkwardType) = 
      someFn input = 42
```

And here's the more straightforward (in my opinion) way to generate the input:

```
module Tests =
   let [Property] ``Test using straightforward generation`` (name, id, flag) = 
      let input = SomeAwkwardType( name, id, flag )
      someFn input = 42
```

This is not only shorter and cleaner, but also has the advantage of not pulling your hair a year later having to look all over the codebase for the static class that implements the generator.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try later, probably tomorrow.

Comment: It worked perfect! Arb.Default.Derive did the trick, so I was able to do the adjustments to the generated values wihout causing the endless recursion. When it comes to your other suggestion (using more straighforward way to generate input), it definitely looks cleaner in that particular test. But when the chosen approach is defining custom SomeAckwardTypePropertyAttribute then going back to [Property] and sending to tests sets of individual values instead of the acward type instance has its drawbacks too. So I'd rather use Derive as you suggested.